# Fitting data to binomial or bernoulli distributions

Tags: binomial-distribution, fitting, bernoulli-distribution, geometric-distribution

I'm trying to fit a count variable to discrete distribution, poisson and negative binomial are not the best candidate to my data since i have only 3 possible values: 0,1 or 2 (sometimes 2) . Can someone help me and tell me how can fit my data to binomial or bernoulli in R

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? What is your data (how did you obtain it, what it means)? The simplest choice - without knowing more about your data - is categorical distribution.

Comment: i'm trying to estimate the distribution of the number of optical claims per year. I applied : fitdist function (in R) but it does not work for binomial and bernoulli distribution. I want to know the syntax.

Comment: If it's only about `fitdistr`, then it's off-topic, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic If it's about underlying statistical problem, then it's on-topic. However in the second case it'd be good if you edited your post to tell us more about your data.

Comment: When you say "only 3 possible values" is it that you cannot claim more than twice under the policy? If so, I'd consider a truncated Poisson/Negative binomial.Alternatively one might consider simply modelling  P(Y=0), P(Y=1) and P(Y=2) (if you have predictors, by modeling  P(Y=0|X), P(Y=1|Y>0,X) and P(Y=2|Y>0,X) -- eg. by doing it as a pair of logistic regressions)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to estimate the distribution of the number of optical
>   claims per year.

From the limited information that you provided, I'd rather think about [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). It has pmf of form

$$ f(x) = (1-p)^x p $$

where $x \ge 0$ and $0 < p \le 1$. It's parameter $p$ is a probability of success, and $x$ is the number of failures until success.

In your case, you can think of $p$ as of probability of having no claims for a whole year and $q = 1-p$ is a probability of a single claim happening.

This parameter can be easily estimated from your data using maximum likelihood

$$ \hat p = \frac{n}{n + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i} $$

or Bayesian approach

$$ \hat p \sim \mathrm{Beta}(\alpha + n, \beta + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i) $$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are parameters of conjugate [Beta prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), e.g. $\alpha = \beta = 1$ for uniform, "uninformative" prior.